# Deteting islands of different color in an image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

Suppose I have an image with a single colored background(say black) which has a lot of 'islands' of different color. Imagine a black background with say red, yellow and green patches of color scattered throughout. I want a program that will draw a contour around all these patches. I am using opencv with python. I already found the program to draw contour if the color is predefined. If not, what can I do? And there is not specific shape foe these patches.

Comment: Detect edges then apply contour detection

Comment: It would help if you added a link to a sample image.

Comment: So you can "draw contour if the color is predefined"? Doesnt OpenCV have `IF or Else` statements? Predefine "black" then `If` black = do nothing, `Else` = draw contours?

Comment: Can you provide a sample image that you are working with?

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('img.jpg')
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)

_,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, 1, 2)
for cnt in contours:
    (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    radius = int(radius)
    cv2.circle(img,center,radius,(255,255,255),2)

cv2.imshow('Detected!',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## Result:

[image]